# Image links copy

Tags: php, html, image, hyperlink

I want to copy the images links from this site (http://lolrotation.ovh/rfreekr - images are automatically changed each week), but the modified link.

For example:

**[their web]** `<img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/shared/riot/images/champions/268.png">`

*↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ automatically changes to ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓*

**[my web]** **`<img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/v2/champions/icons/size64x64/268.png">`**

Can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source code, you will see it is a Word Press Plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/league-of-legends-rotation/

Comment: I know, but it does not show some of the new champions, because the link to images is outdated.